# Shell script to parse variable definitions from Scala build file

Tags: parsing, bash, scala, shell

The `build.sbt` text file contains versions like this:

```
name := "happy"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
sparkVersion := "2.2.0"
```

I wrote a Bash script to parse out the `PROJECT_NAME` and `SCALA_VERSION` from the `build.sbt` file:

```
PROJECT_NAME=$(cat build.sbt | grep "name :=" | cut -f 3 -d " " | tr -d '"')
SCALA_VERSION=$(cat build.sbt | grep "scalaVersion :=" | cut -f 3 -d " " | tr -d '"')
```

How can I write this more elegantly / robustly?  I'm ok with an `awk` or `sed` approach, but don't want to add an external dependency to the script.

Here's some more of the script to see how the variables are being used.

```
if [ "$SCALA_VERSION" = "" ]
  then
    echo "SCALA_VERSION variable cannot be empty"
    exit 1
fi

SCALA_BINARY_VERSION=${SCALA_VERSION%.*}
if [ "$SCALA_BINARY_VERSION" = "" ]
  then
    echo "SCALA_BINARY_VERSION variable cannot be empty"
    exit 1
fi

echo "Create a GitHub release"
JAR_PATH=target/scala-${SCALA_BINARY_VERSION}/${PROJECT_NAME}_${SCALA_BINARY_VERSION}-${SPARK_VERSION}_${PROJECT_VERSION}.jar
hub release create -a $JAR_PATH -m "Release v${PROJECT_VERSION}" v${PROJECT_VERSION}
```

Comment: Could you also show more of the Bash script, where you use the variables?

Comment: @200_success - Sure, I updated the post to show more of the script, thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you don't mind spinning up `sbt` to extract the settings keys you could use the following:

```
PROJECT_NAME="$(sbt name | tail -1)"
PROJECT_NAME="${PROJECT_NAME#* }"

SCALA_VERSION="$(sbt scalaVersion | tail -1)"
SCALA_VERSION="${SCALA_VERSION#* }"

echo $PROJECT_NAME
echo $SCALA_VERSION
```

Comment: `sbt -no-colors name` is even better to remove ANSI color codes from the text stream

Answer (score 3):

I'd use awk to generate shell syntax, and `source` it in the shell:

```
$ source <(
    awk '
        $1 == "name"         {print "PROJECT_NAME=" $NF}
        $1 == "scalaVersion" {print "SCALA_VERSION=" $NF}
    ' build.sbt
)

$ echo $PROJECT_NAME,$SCALA_VERSION
happy,2.11.8
```

If the name or version strings might contain spaces, then we need to be more specific about awk's field separator:

```
$ cat build.sbt
name := "hello world"
scalaVersion := "2.11.8"
sparkVersion := "2.2.0"

$ awk '
    $1 == "name"         {print "PROJECT_NAME=" $NF}
    $1 == "scalaVersion" {print "SCALA_VERSION=" $NF}
' build.sbt

PROJECT_NAME=world"              # << oops
SCALA_VERSION="2.11.8"

$ awk -F '"' '
    $1 ~ /^name/         {printf "PROJECT_NAME=\"%s\"\n",  $2}
    $1 ~ /^scalaVersion/ {printf "SCALA_VERSION=\"%s\"\n", $2}
' build.sbt

PROJECT_NAME="hello world"
SCALA_VERSION="2.11.8"
```

Answer (score 0):

No one else has mentioned this, so I’ll add it here. There is no need to `cat file | grep pattern`. I might do it in an interactive shell if I forget which parameter is which, but for a script it is needless.

In

```
PROJECT_NAME=$(cat build.sbt | grep "name :=" | cut -f 3 -d " " | tr -d '"')
SCALA_VERSION=$(cat build.sbt | grep "scalaVersion :=" | cut -f 3 -d " " | tr -d '"')
```

prefer `grep file pattern` usage. Grep can read the file for you; no need for cat and a pipe.

Comment: Or alternately `<file grep`

Comment: Instead of adding a comment with more context, please [edit] and add the additional information. Refer to the section **When _shouldn't_ I comment?** on [Comment everywhere](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).